# How to initialize Spring service without Autowired?

Tags: java, spring

I am creating a Logger object manually and Spring doesn't initialize UserService as expected. How can I force Spring to initialize UserService?

I tried below code but it doesn't initialize;

```
WebApplicationContext context = ContextLoader.getCurrentWebApplicationContext();
userService = context.getBean(UserService.class);
```

Here is JobService;

```
@Service
public class JobService{
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JobService.class);

    doJob(){
        logger.info("Job is starting...");
        .....
    }
}
```

My LoggerFactory;

```
public class LoggerFactory {

  public static Logger getLogger(Class clazz) {
    Logger logger = new Logger(clazz);
    return logger;
  }

  private LoggerFactory() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not instantiable");
  }

}
```

And my Logger;

```
public class Logger {
    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    public void info(String message){
        User user = userService.getCurrentUser(); //userService is null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You instantiate a `Logger` using `LoggerFactory`, not the Spring bean factory.

`Logger` is not a Spring component.  That means Spring is not responsible for wiring its dependencies.

The moment you do that it's out of Spring's control.

I don't think this dependency is correct.  The `Logger` should not have a service; it ought to be the other way around.

Get the user information from the service and pass it into the `Logger`.

If you have no alternative, then you need to have Spring instantiate the Logger as a bean.  Then you have to inject that into the *thousands* of classes you claim.

I still say that the second alternative is a bigger problem.

I'd wonder why thousands of classes have to do the same thing.  Wouldn't it be better to log in an aspect and do it in one place?

Your question suggests that you have bigger problems in your system.

Comment: I can't get the user information and pass it into the Logger because I need to add user information to for all project.(I got thousands of classes) Isn't there any workaround way to initialize UserService?

Comment: Sounds like an awful design.  Thousands?  I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify @ComponentScan by annotation or in XML like this:

But I think your error is that your Logger class isn't a bean. You can only autowire beans on bean classes. By default, beans are singleton instances and you are using a Factory approach. Take a look at Factory Beans: https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/09/what-s-a-factorybean